# How can I get a file on a FTP server where the file starts with a specific characters

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my script:

```
import os
from ftplib import FTP
```

I didn't want to put the IP so I put "my ip" instead:

```
ftp = FTP("my ip")
ftp.login()
ftp.retrlines("LIST")

def grabFile():
    listing = []
    ftp.retrlines("LIST", listing.append)
    words = listing[-1].split(None, 8)
    print("words", words)
    filename = words[-1].lstrip()
    print("filename:", filename)
```

This is where I download the file:

```
    local_filename = os.path.join(r"/Users/Ranjivman/Desktop/OCD/FILES", filename)
    lf = open(local_filename, "wb")
    ftp.retrbinary("RETR " + filename, lf.write, 8*1024)
    lf.close()
```

Comment: you didn't actually ask a question, whats the issue with your current code?

Comment: My issue is that it only downloads the latest file, but I need it to download the file that starts with specific character. For example I have files pdd1112 and xhd321, I need to download where it starts with "pdd". I'm a bit newbie on python and can't seem find a way on the internet.

Comment: you select the wrong `filename` try looking at the list of names before selecting, you can get just the file names from your output with something like this `[item.split()[-1] for item in listing]` (This wont work if there are spaces in your file names)

Comment: Perhaps `ftp.nlst` would be of help. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.nlst